# Spring. Class loader

Tags: java, spring

I have the following problem.

It is necessary for me that the classes implementing the certain interface automatically became beans(like with `@Component`).

For example, I have package `com.test` with `context:component-scan base-package="com.test"` that has two classes. One of them has annotation `@Component`, but other only implements specific interface.

I need a class with this interface to become a bean as well as a class with an annotation.

How can i do this?

Comment: Specify an `include-filter` for your `context:component-scan` element. That way you can add additional rules for what needs to be included as a bean.

Answer (score 0):

You can add annotation @Component or @Service to your class and it wil be bean or you could add you class as @Bean to your spring configuration

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this

1. Add Spring Stereotype `@Componenet`, `@Serivce`, `@Repository` etc. based on your type of class
2. Explicitly define the Bean in your configurations

   ```
   @Bean
   public InterfaceType methodname(){
       return new Implementation();
   }
   ```
3. Programmatically using `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory`

   ```
   @Configuration
   @DependsOn("ContextProvider") //Not sure whether we need this
   public class BeanConfig  implements BeanFactoryAware {
       private BeanFactory beanFactory;

       @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
       private void createBean() throws Exception{
           if(null == beanFactory){
               throw new Exception("Couldnot load Bean Factory");
           }

           ConfigurableBeanFactory configurableBeanFactory = (ConfigurableBeanFactory) beanFactory;

           configurableBeanFactory.registerSingleton("name", implementation);;

       }
   }
   ```

   *If you have multiple implementations of an interface then please provide a name with Bean or Stereotype Annotations and use that name while Autowiring.*

Comment: There is no way to define a bean just by the interface(without any annotations and xml declaration)? For example, register a listener where all classes scanned by spring will be passed during initialization?

Comment: Updated answer. Added 3rd option using programming

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to access all classes implementing a given interface and then add them manually to your context but please don't.

Just add @Component (and @Qualifier("beanName") if you have more than one bean implementing this interface)